# Adding Manifest Json on index.html

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, manifest

I am trying to Implement a firebase notification on angular. However when I added manifest.json at src/ and had referenced it at index.html as  `<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">`
but the browser is giving me two errors 404 not found and
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error
when I checked it with dom and opened it via a new tab it is redirected to my index without loading the resource I have tried some solutions and none of them seems to work. The error only seems to go away when I comment on that line on the index.
I am currently using angular version 7.1.0

---

angular.json

```
{
  
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Ang7": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Ang7",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/w3.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/assets/css/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Ang7:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Ang7:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Ang7:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
       
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
    "Ang7-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Ang7:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Ang7:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Ang7",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "2655066d-910d-4521-b978-37a981395ab1"
  }
}
```

---

manifest.json

```
  {
    "gcmsender_id":"654616556484"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you missed to add it in `angular.json` file.

Ensure your angular.json structure contains `manifest.json` file.

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "manifest.json"  // <-- Must be included
            ],
          ...
}
```

Comment: I have already added it on angular.json it is in the directory src/manifest.json, but it doesn't seem to work. As the error is not going away

Comment: Can you share your `angular.json` and `manifest.json` file too?

Comment: please take a look as i have shared them above

Answer (score 1):

1. Add src/manifest.json to your assets array in your angular.json
     `"assets": ["src/assets", "src/favicon.ico", "src/manifest.json"],`
2. Restart your server